# Tic-Tac-Toe button images dissapearing after clicking another button

Tags: python, image, button, tkinter

When a button is clicked X appears as intended but once another button is clicked the x moves to that button and the previous button goes blank and can no longer be clicked.

I want the X image to remain after I click on a new button. I have no idea why the previous button's X image disappears. Also don't mind the commented out part in my function. I was working on a way to switch between player 1 and player 2, but I first need to get the images to actually appear properly on the buttons.

[X](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zoci2.png)

```
 from tkinter import *

def openGame():
    root.deiconify()
    menu.withdraw()
    e1txt.set("X Player 1: " + e1.get())
    e2txt.set("O Player 2: " + e2.get())
    turnlabeltxt.set(e1.get() + "'s turn")

turn = 1
def call(button):
    global turn
    global photo
    if turn == 1: #turn%2 == 1:
        photo = PhotoImage(file="X.png").subsample(15)
        button.config(image=photo)

        #turn += 1

#     if (turn%2) == 0:
#         photo = PhotoImage(file="Circle.png")
#         button.config(image=photo)
#         turn += 1
#Not messing with turn switching until I can get these darned images to work correctly

root = Tk()
root.title("Tic Tac Toe")
root.geometry("500x350")
root.resizable(True, True)
root.withdraw()

photo = PhotoImage(file="").subsample(15)
square = 85
e1txt = StringVar()
e2txt = StringVar()

b1 = Button(root, image=photo, compound=CENTER, height=square, width=square, command=lambda: call(b1))
b1.grid(row=0, column=0, padx=2, pady=2)
b2 = Button(root, image=photo, compound=CENTER, height=square, width=square, command=lambda: call(b2))
b2.grid(row=0, column=1, padx=2, pady=2)
b3 = Button(root, image=photo, compound=CENTER, height=square, width=square, command=lambda: call(b3))
b3.grid(row=0, column=2, padx=2, pady=2)

b4 = Button(root, image=photo, compound=CENTER, height=square, width=square, command=lambda: call(b4))
b4.grid(row=1, column=0, padx=2, pady=2)
b5 = Button(root, image=photo, compound=CENTER, height=square, width=square, command=lambda: call(b5))
b5.grid(row=1, column=1, padx=2, pady=2)
b6 = Button(root, image=photo, compound=CENTER, height=square, width=square, command=lambda: call(b6))
b6.grid(row=1, column=2, padx=2, pady=2)

b7 = Button(root, image=photo, compound=CENTER, height=square, width=square, command=lambda: call(b7))
b7.grid(row=2, column=0, padx=2, pady=2)
b8 = Button(root, image=photo, compound=CENTER, height=square, width=square, command=lambda: call(b8))
b8.grid(row=2, column=1, padx=2, pady=2)
b9 = Button(root, image=photo, compound=CENTER, height=square, width=square, command=lambda: call(b9))
b9.grid(row=2, column=2, padx=2, pady=2)


P1 = Label(root, textvariable=e1txt)
P1.grid(row=0, column=3, sticky=W)

P2 = Label(root, textvariable=e2txt)
P2.grid(row=1, column=3, sticky=W)

menu = Toplevel()
menu.title("Player names")
menu.geometry("265x80")
menu.resizable(False, False)

p1 = Label(menu, text="X Player 1:")
p1.grid(row = 0, column = 0)
p2 = Label(menu, text="O Player 2:")
p2.grid(row = 2, column = 0)


e1 = Entry(menu)
e1.grid(row=0, column=1)
e2 = Entry(menu)
e2.grid(row=2, column=1)
button = Button(menu, text="Start Game", command=openGame)
button.grid(row=9, column=9)

turnlabeltxt = StringVar()
turnlabel = Label(root, textvariable=turnlabeltxt)
turnlabel.grid(row=3, column=3)
```

Comment: `global` is probably causing issues here, but I didn't do a deep dive into troubleshooting.

Comment: I updated the original post since I had issues posting the question at first. Could you check out the new post and see if you think global is still an issue?

Comment: Probably. What I think is happening is you are updating the `photo` to a different location which moves it instead of adds another one. I think if you just take `global photo` out of the `call` function that would go away. No promise that fixes the issue though.

Comment: if you have many images then you should keep them on global list. You can't keep many images using only `photo = ...` because it removes previous image from variable and system removes it from memory and image doesn't exist.

Comment: maybe instead of loading the same imaga many times you should load it only once at start and later assign to different buttons.

Comment: You recreate `photo` everytime you click a button, so the last image will be garbaged.  You only need create the `photo` once.

Answer (score 0):

If you load many images then you would have to keep them in many variables or on one list.

But you could load iamge only once and later assign the same images to many buttons

At start

```
photo = PhotoImage(file="").subsample(15)
photo_x = PhotoImage(file="X.png").subsample(15)
photo_o = PhotoImage(file="O.png").subsample(15)
```

and later without loading

```
def call(button):
    global turn
    global photo
    if turn == 1: #turn%2 == 1:
        button.config(image=photo_x)
```

---

Full code

```
from tkinter import *

def openGame():
    root.deiconify()
    menu.withdraw()
    e1txt.set("X Player 1: " + e1.get())
    e2txt.set("O Player 2: " + e2.get())
    turnlabeltxt.set(e1.get() + "'s turn")

turn = 1
def call(button):
    global turn
    if turn == 1: #turn%2 == 1:
        button.config(image=photo_x)

        #turn += 1

#     if (turn%2) == 0:
#         button.config(image=photo_o)
#         turn += 1
#Not messing with turn switching until I can get these darned images to work correctly

root = Tk()
root.title("Tic Tac Toe")
root.geometry("500x350")
root.resizable(True, True)
root.withdraw()

photo = PhotoImage(file="").subsample(15)
photo_x = PhotoImage(file="X.png").subsample(15)
photo_o = PhotoImage(file="Circle.png").subsample(15)

square = 85
e1txt = StringVar()
e2txt = StringVar()

b1 = Button(root, image=photo, compound=CENTER, height=square, width=square, command=lambda: call(b1))
b1.grid(row=0, column=0, padx=2, pady=2)
b2 = Button(root, image=photo, compound=CENTER, height=square, width=square, command=lambda: call(b2))
b2.grid(row=0, column=1, padx=2, pady=2)
b3 = Button(root, image=photo, compound=CENTER, height=square, width=square, command=lambda: call(b3))
b3.grid(row=0, column=2, padx=2, pady=2)

b4 = Button(root, image=photo, compound=CENTER, height=square, width=square, command=lambda: call(b4))
b4.grid(row=1, column=0, padx=2, pady=2)
b5 = Button(root, image=photo, compound=CENTER, height=square, width=square, command=lambda: call(b5))
b5.grid(row=1, column=1, padx=2, pady=2)
b6 = Button(root, image=photo, compound=CENTER, height=square, width=square, command=lambda: call(b6))
b6.grid(row=1, column=2, padx=2, pady=2)

b7 = Button(root, image=photo, compound=CENTER, height=square, width=square, command=lambda: call(b7))
b7.grid(row=2, column=0, padx=2, pady=2)
b8 = Button(root, image=photo, compound=CENTER, height=square, width=square, command=lambda: call(b8))
b8.grid(row=2, column=1, padx=2, pady=2)
b9 = Button(root, image=photo, compound=CENTER, height=square, width=square, command=lambda: call(b9))
b9.grid(row=2, column=2, padx=2, pady=2)


P1 = Label(root, textvariable=e1txt)
P1.grid(row=0, column=3, sticky=W)

P2 = Label(root, textvariable=e2txt)
P2.grid(row=1, column=3, sticky=W)

menu = Toplevel()
menu.title("Player names")
menu.geometry("265x80")
menu.resizable(False, False)

p1 = Label(menu, text="X Player 1:")
p1.grid(row = 0, column = 0)
p2 = Label(menu, text="O Player 2:")
p2.grid(row = 2, column = 0)

e1 = Entry(menu)
e1.grid(row=0, column=1)
e2 = Entry(menu)
e2.grid(row=2, column=1)
button = Button(menu, text="Start Game", command=openGame)
button.grid(row=9, column=9)

turnlabeltxt = StringVar()
turnlabel = Label(root, textvariable=turnlabeltxt)
turnlabel.grid(row=3, column=3)

root.mainloop()
```

---

**EDIT:** code with other changes:

```
#from tkinter import * # not preferred
import tkinter as tk

# --- function --- 
def open_game():
    root.deiconify()
    menu.withdraw()
    turn_name_var.set( name1_var.get() )

def call(button):
    global turn

    if turn%2 == 1:
        button.config(image=photo_x)
        turn_name_var.set( name2_var.get() )
    else:
        button.config(image=photo_o)
        turn_name_var.set( name1_var.get() )

    turn += 1

# --- main ---

# --- constants --- (UPPER_CASE_NAMES)

SQUARE = 85

# --- variables ---

turn = 1

# ---

root = tk.Tk()
root.title("Tic Tac Toe")
#root.geometry("500x350")
#root.resizable(False, False)
root.withdraw()

# ---

name1_var = tk.StringVar()
name2_var = tk.StringVar()
turn_name_var = tk.StringVar()

# ---

photo = tk.PhotoImage(file="").subsample(15)
#photo_x = tk.PhotoImage(file="X.png").subsample(15)
#photo_o = tk.PhotoImage(file="O.png").subsample(15)
photo_x = tk.PhotoImage(file="square-1.png")#.subsample(15)
photo_o = tk.PhotoImage(file="square-2.png")#.subsample(15)

# ---

frame = tk.Frame(root)
frame.pack(padx=10, pady=10)

#buttons = []
for x in range(3):
    for y in range(3):
       b = tk.Button(frame, image=photo, compound='center', height=SQUARE, width=SQUARE)
       b['command'] = lambda c=b:call(c)
       b.grid(row=y*2, column=x, padx=2, pady=2, rowspan=2)
       #buttons.append(b)

tk.Label(frame, text="X Player 1:").grid(row=0, column=3)
tk.Label(frame, textvar=name1_var).grid(row=1, column=3)

tk.Label(frame, text="O Player 2:").grid(row=2, column=3)
tk.Label(frame, textvar=name2_var).grid(row=3, column=3)

tk.Label(frame, text="Turn:").grid(row=4, column=3)
tk.Label(frame, textvar=turn_name_var).grid(row=5, column=3)

# ---

menu = tk.Toplevel()
menu.title("Player names")
#menu.geometry("265x80")
menu.resizable(False, False)

tk.Label(menu, text="X Player 1:").grid(row=0, column=0)
tk.Label(menu, text="O Player 2:").grid(row=1, column=0)

tk.Entry(menu, textvar=name1_var).grid(row=0, column=1)
tk.Entry(menu, textvar=name2_var).grid(row=1, column=1)

tk.Button(menu, text="Start Game", command=open_game).grid(row=2, column=0, columnspan=2)

# ---

root.mainloop()
```

[image]

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]